# jquery code works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE11

Tags: html, jquery

I encountered a slight problem. My jQuery code works as expected in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE11. Not sure why it's not working.

Here is my HTML, CSS and jQuery:

```js
let nodes = $('h2').contents().filter(function(i, node) {
  return node.nodeType === 3;
});
Array.from(nodes).forEach(function(n) {
  return n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.trim();
});
```

```css
h2 img {
  width: 31px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>This is a test <img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" /></h2>
<h2>This is another test <img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" /></h2>
<h2>foo bar <img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" /></h2>
```

Would like it to work in IE11 as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what makes you think this is a jQuery problem? You barely use any jQuery here. What error does the dev console show?

Comment: I went ahead and created a code snippet. No error. works as expected in Chrome and Firefox and Chrome just not in IE11. As you can see when the snippet is ran it produces the output but not in IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.from` is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#browser_compatibility) in Internet Explorer.

As you use jQuery, just call `.each` on the `nodes` collection:

```
nodes.each(function(_, n) {
  n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.trim();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot. Quick question why the _ in the function?

Comment: It is an argument that represents the *index*, but since I have no use for it, I use the name `_`, so the reader understands I am not going to use it.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Makes sense now :)